# Flatten an object preserving certain Fields

Tags: javascript

I would like to flatten this object without flattening the keys $gt and $lt

```
{
 values:{
  gross_floor_area:{"$gt":200, "$lt":5000},
  nested: {net_floor_area:{"$gt":200, "$lt":5000}}
}}
```

the desired result would be

```
{ 'values.gross_floor_area':  { '$gt': 200, '$lt': 5000 },'values.nested.net_floor_area':{"$gt":200, "$lt":5000} }
```

I have tried using [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) library by specifying maxDepth of 2 but only works for *gross_floor_area* key

Comment: so ... is it the fact that those keys begin with `$` that signifies "don't flatten me"? because I can imagine it's easy to write code to do that

Comment: Is that the full extent of the object or just an example? If that's it why not just assign the object values to a new object with those keys.

Comment: yes all those keys that begins with $ should not be flattened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the flattened object, without mutating the original object.

```
function flatten(obj) {
  const result = {};
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !obj[key].$gt && !obj[key].$lt) {
      const flatObject = flatten(obj[key]);
      for (const x in flatObject) {
        result[`${key}.${x}`] = flatObject[x];
      }
    } else {
      result[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

It doesn't work for all keys starting with `$`, as you mentioned in the comment to your question, only `$gt` and `$lt`. More specifically, it won't flatten the object that contains these two keys.

FYI, this was pretty much generated by GitHub Copilot. In case you use it, it's very helpful for achieving this kind of goals.

Comment: @Rickhomes I edited my answer to not mutate the object.